# What would be a ec2 unit equivalent of a X5670 hex core xeon

Tags: amazon-ec2, central-processing-unit, intel

A ec2 compute unit is 1.0-1.2 GHz 2007 Opteron or 2007 Xeon processor.

I'm looking at a X5670 hex core xeon: http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=47920

Is it even possible to compare the 2?

I'm looking for a rough idea, something like:

12 x ec2 compute unit = X5670

Answer (score 2):

Each core on the X5670 is 2.93Ghz (we'll go with 3 to keep the math easy).

3 Ghz * 6 Cores = 18 Ghz of CPU power which would be about 18 EC2 Computer Units.

Depending on your application this might be better or worse.  Some apps need a few fast CPUs, (like databases) others want lots of cores so that more threads can be run at a time.

Comment: but on ec2 its all about cores, not really much choice right?   so a mysql db would need high memory, lower cpu and fast io right?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do with it, and how tight your database code and design is.  A sight with a really tight database design and really tight database code would run really differently than one with a crappy database design or bad code.  How many EC2 CUs were you looking at getting in your machine?  An EC2 CU just maps to a physical core, which may or may not be shared with other VMs on the server.

Comment: not to mention bare metal servers being generally much faster! orders of magnitude at times i.e. 2-3x or more.